# How to extract surfaces from an 3d array (volume)

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I create a 3d array like this:

```
arr = np.zeros((100, 100))
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        arr[i*20:(i+1)*20, j*20:(j+1)*20] = i+1
arr = np.tile(arr[np.newaxis,:,:], (100,1,1))
arr = np.transpose(arr, (0, 2, 1))
```

The resulting shape will be `(100,100,100)`. It will look like this at `y=50`:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(5, 5))
y=50
x, z = np.arange(arr.shape[0]), np.arange(arr.shape[2])
xv, zv = np.meshgrid(x,z)
plt.pcolormesh(xv, zv, arr[:,y,:].T, cmap='plasma')
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('z')
plt.title('3d array - y:{}'.format(y))
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Now I want to create the interfaces between these regions, in this array there are 5 regions, determined by the values (1,2,3,4 and 5), so the resulting interfaces will be 4, how can they be estimated and stored in another array to later plot them as surfaces like [this](https://plotly.com/python/3d-surface-plots/#multiple-3d-surface-plots)?

Comment: Won't the so-called interfaces just be regularly spaced planes with equal orientation? Why is that interesting to plot?

Comment: I`m trying to plot the raypaths of reflected seismic waves so I need to show the reflection at the interface like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Diagram_of_a_marine_seismic_survey.png)

Comment: What I'm saying is, your example data set you up for a trivial solution that probably won't work for your real data. Consider making them at least nonlinear.

Comment: Do you want colour mapped planar slices through your volume, or do you want nonplanar isosurfaces through your volume for chosen values? It seems like the latter

Comment: @Reinderien I understand your concern, but, in geophysics, the simplest model is a flat layered stratified earth, in which velocity increases with depth. If my raytracing does not work with this model, it will not work with a more complex model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import PolyCollection

# Delete all of your existing code and replace with the equivalent
arr = np.tile(np.arange(1, 6).repeat(20), (100, 100, 1))

# ...but delete that, too. Your "interface" planes are trivially defined via:
verts = np.zeros((4, 4, 2))
verts[:, 2:, 0] = 100
verts[:, 1:3, 1] = 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})
facecolors = plt.colormaps['plasma'](np.linspace(0, 1, len(verts)))
poly = PolyCollection(verts, facecolors=facecolors, alpha=.7)
ax.add_collection3d(poly, zs=np.arange(20, 100, 20), zdir='y')
ax.set(xlim=(0, 100), xlabel='x',
       ylim=(0, 100), ylabel='z',
       zlim=(0, 100), zlabel='y')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot]